# Очень долго загружаются страницы в веб приложении на php Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, веб-программирование, frontend

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]В настоящее время я создаю веб-приложение с использованием Laravel 6, PHP 7.2 и OpenServer (localhost). Мое приложение представляет собой панель администратора на основе SB-ADMIN-2.

Когда я загружаю веб-страницу, она загружается в течение примерно 4 секунд, но для текущего проекта это нужно около 1 секунды, максимум 2 секунды.

Спасибо за помощь заранее. Мой код blade.php содержит файлы js. Я устанавливал SB-ADMIN-2 на свой второй проект без создания файлов Conrtollers и blade.php, только html и веб-маршрутизации, и работал он быстрее, чем в моем проекте с файлами Controllers и blade.php. Я копирую свой второй проект в мой первый, заменяю html-файлы на файлы blade.php, затем создаю контроллеры и маршрутизацию, а затем просматриваю его, а загрузка моего веб-приложения происходит очень[image: введите сюда описание изображения] медленно. Моя БД не переполнена, у нее 15 строк в таблицах пользователей, и мой сайт падает с сообщением слишком большого запроса (600 МБ).

Ну а вывод осуществляется вот так в блэйде:

```html
> @foreach($users as $user)
>                                 <tr><td>{{$user->id}}</td>
>                                     <td>{{$user->first_name}}</td>
>                                     <td>{{$user->last_name}}</td>
>                                     <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
>                                     <td>{{$user->approve}}</td>
>                                     <td>{{$user->active}}</td>
>                                     <td>{{$user->$users = DB::table('departments')->value('name')}}</td> <td>
```

Вот код в контроллере для метода

```
index  public function index()
    {
        $users = User::all();
        return view('approved', ['users'=>$users]);
    }
```

UPD. Скриншот загрузки
UPD. Ошибка: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException Out of memory (allocated 639631360) (tried to allocate 281022464 bytes)

Comment: css файлы пхп выдает что ли,  не апач напрямую? про 600мбайт, это я так понимаю пхп падает с ошибкой что не может память выделить,  или что? давайте код экшенов, где падает.

Comment: используйте ссылку [edit] и отредактируйте вопрос, не надо код вставлять в комментарии

Comment: подозреваю, что js/css файлы из vendor выводятся через пхп. чтобы этого не было,  надо папки плагинов залинковать в корень сайта. сделат симлинк, чтобы это были реальные пути к файлам. будет их отдавать апач за 30мс, а не пхп

Comment: `$user->$users` это нормально ли?

Comment: @teran А что не так?

Comment: то что переменная `$users` у вас уже определена, и это массив, а вы пытаетесь использовать ее в качестве имени поля, или blade этот имеет какой-то специфический отличный от пхп синтаксис? и да. не надо выполнять запросы к БД из шаблона, загрузите все что надо в контроллере/модели.

Comment: @teran А как потом выводить в шаблоне? Я просто новичок в этой сфере, 2 месяца, не знаю многих ньюансов и правил :)

Comment: Пока определяй данные в контроллере (потом сервисы будешь писать для более сложной логики). Эти данные передавай в шаблон. В шаблоне всего лишь выводи данные. `$user->$users` - явная ошибка в данном контексте